# Why I can't show the browser version using JQuery 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-2.0

I am pretty new in JavaScript and JQuery and I have the following problem.

I have included **JQuery 2.1.4** and I am tryng to implement a very simple JQuery script that show thw browser name and its version.

So I am trying to follow this official documentation "tutorial": http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/

So, into my page, I done something like this:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert($.browser.version);
    });

</script>
```

But it don't works infact the popup is not shown and into the FireBug console I obtain the following error message:

```
TypeError: $.browser is undefined
    alert($.browser.version);
```

Why? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser detection in JQuery 2.0 and higher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115650/browser-detection-in-jquery-2-0-and-higher)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature of `$.browser` is deprecated from jQuery v 1.3 and is removed from the jQuery `1.9`, so you cannot use it in the jQuery version 2.

From the [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/):

> Description: Contains flags for the useragent, read from navigator.userAgent. **This property was removed in jQuery 1.9** and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin. Please try to use feature detection instead.

Comment: Ok and so using JQuery 2 what can I do to obtain the browser name and the broswer version?

Comment: @AndreaNobili Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser